# How to join socket chat room

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

With the help of [this guide](http://www.tamas.io/advanced-chat-using-node-js-and-socket-io-episode-1/), I'm trying to build a socket chat. It's almost done, however, users can't join other's room. The code below is my 'joining room function':

```
    client.on("joinRoom", function(id) {  
var room = rooms[id];
if (client.id === room.owner) {
  client.emit("update", "You are the owner of this room and you have already been joined.");
} else {
  room.people.contains(client.id, function(found) {
      if (found) {
          client.emit("update", "You have already joined this room.");
      } else {
        if (people[client.id].inroom !== null) { //make sure that one person joins one room at a time
            console.log("User is already in a room");
          client.emit("update", "You are already in a room ("+rooms[people[client.id].inroom].name+"), please leave it first to join another room.");
        } else {
      room.addPerson(client.id);
      people[client.id].inroom = id;
      client.room = room.name;
      client.join(client.room); //add person to the room
      user = people[client.id];
      socket.sockets.in(client.room).emit("update", user.name + " has connected to " + room.name + " room.");
      client.emit("update", "Welcome to " + room.name + ".");
      client.emit("sendRoomID", {id: id});
    }
      }
  });
}
});
```

When a user tries to join someone's room, the function stops at the 'update' that informs that the user is already in a room. Why is that?

Comment: where's the link of the guide? All I see is ???

Comment: Sorry. It's still early in the morning here :-) I have added it

Comment: the reason why it stopped at user is already in a room is because people[client.id].inroom is not null. try adding console.log(people[client.id]["room"]); right after console.log("User is already in a room"); and post here what it prints.

Comment: It prints null.

Comment: alright. makes sense. it means the person hasn't created a room of his own yet. try printing out this now: console.log(people[client.id]["inroom"]); and let me know what is the result

Comment: It prints undefined

Comment: alright now print: console.log(people[client.id].inroom); my javascript is a little rusty atm so pardon me. lol

Comment: Haha no worries. It still prints undefined

Comment: I've posted an answer, let me know if that fixes the problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is !==.

Change

```
if (people[client.id].inroom !== null) {
```

to

```
if (people[client.id].inroom != null) {
```

undefined !== null is giving you true but you essentially want undefined to act as if it was equivalent to null. !== will actually see them as separate whereas != will see them as equivalent, which is what you want.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks @DiderDrogba344. I didn't think that the fix would be so simple :-)

Comment: np! glad that I could help! :)